# In Active Directory, does a bind affects what's visible?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When I connect and bind to an Active Directory, does the binding user account affect what directory objects are visible (queriable)?

For example, if I did LDAP bind using userA's credentials, I can query for objects O1 and O2, but if I did LDAP bind using userB's credentials, I can query for O2 but not for O1.

If the answer is yes, what properties govern this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes - of course! As in a file system, certain parts of the AD can be made visible only to a select group of users (typically done by giving permissions to a group). AD has a permission system on its directory objects much like a filesystem directory - it uses the same mechanism, too - ACL (Access Control Lists)

Comment: See [Securing Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728372%28WS.10%29.aspx) for an intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As marc_s said, the answer is yes. The ACL is stored in the ntSecurityDescriptor attribute of each object in the directory.

That said, by default, every user can read pretty much everything in the directory. You've got to do a bunch of extra work to make it so some objects don't show up for some users.